# Squid3 failing to install via apt

Tags: debian, squid

I am trying to update `squid3` on my Debian Wheezy box, via `apt-get`. When I run the upgrade, it's the only package that does not install.

```
# apt-get upgrade -y
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up squid3 (3.1.20-2.2+deb7u2) ...
chown: invalid group: `proxy:proxy\r'
dpkg: error processing squid3 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 squid3
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I have verified that yes, `proxy` exists as both a user in `/etc/passwd`, and as a group in `/etc/group`. A friend figured it was the `\r` at the end, and thought I edited one of those files in Windows (which is false). I did make a backup of those two files, and used the `fromdos` command to change it, but it gives me the same error still.

If I run `dpkg --configure squid3`, it just generates the same output. I have backed up my Squid configuration, uninstalled it (with the `purge` option), and tried reinstalling it, but that does not work either. The `proxy` user and group own the caching folder, and the logs folder for itself (`/var/log/squid3`), so I don't think it's in there.

Where else can I look, and what can I do about this error? Yes, it reports it's still running, but I'd like to keep the latest version from the Debian repositories on this system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking in the postinst script (`/var/lib/dpkg/info/squid3.postinst`), this part stands out:

```shell
cache_dir=`grepconf2 cache_dir /var/spool/squid3`
usr=`grepconf cache_effective_user proxy`
grp=`grepconf cache_effective_group proxy`

if [ "$(stat -c %U $cache_dir)" != "$usr" ] ||
   [ "$(stat -c %G $cache_dir)" != "$grp" ] ; then
        chown $usr:$grp $cache_dir -R
fi
```

Seems likely your squid3 config (`/etc/squid3/squid.conf`) has a `\r` in it somewhere.

Comment: That was it! Weird, I've never edited that file from Windows, only through PuTTY... Thanks though!

Comment: Interrsting conclusion the answer... maybe it would be time to select something other than PuTTY?